# Increment difference between cells

Tags: excel

I'm trying to duplicate data in a sheet with increments of 12 between each cell from a sheet with 1 cell per row. Between the 12-incremented rows there's other data. This means I can't drag to extend the formula. Like this for customer numbers:

```
'SheetA'E3 = 'SheetB'Y2
'SheetA'E15 = 'SheetB'Y3
'SheetA'E27 = 'SheetB'Y4
```

..and so on. I've tried extending 12/24 cells at a time and copying but I can't make it work. Extending doesn't add +1 to one sheet, just +12/+24 to both. Doing this manually will take months. Can this be done without a VBA solution?

Any suggestions? I'm sorry if my terminology isn't on point here.

SheetA:

[image: Where I want to output Customer numbers]

[image: Data sheet where I find the Customer number and other parameters]

Comment: You could make formulas in new *adjacent* columns in the target sheets, formulas which use a combination of data from the two sheets. In this case, you could just drag down the formulas and perhaps do a subsequent special-paste-as-values then delete one column. Still a lot of work but better than a formula for each value. For anything much better, VBA is called for and fairly straight-forward in this case.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you John. My VBA-skills are terrible, but adding the spacing to the source sheet might be something I could pull off. In any case I might be able to convince the system developers why their system shouldn't need an Excel template with 12 row spacing between each new customer.

Comment: The source is in SheetA and the target is in SheetB ? (or the other way around..)

Comment: This seems like an XY Problem.  Where are those 12 rows of data coming from?  If all of your data is in a table, with a row of labels at one end, and 12 columns of data in the same row, then an optimum solution would not involve doing what you want.  Please post a proper data sample that can be used to replicate your issue.  Also, your version of Excel is important (Office 365?  Other version?  Mac vs Windows?)

Comment: SheetA is a template intended for system reading. It contains various parameters suited for the system in particular. It's 12 rows of that repeated, so each new system user is read every 12th row, with the rows inbetween containing various other parameters for that user.

Comment: SheetB is the raw data I want to fill SheetA with. No idea why the supplier of the template decided that one customer per row in the template would be a bad idea but I believe that the template was never designed to be filled out automatically.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I'm not sure how to to that. A copy-paste generated images of example tables. I've kind of solved it by adding spacing with VBA and copy-pasting, but the data files may look different every time and require a new code every time so I'm still much interested to know if there's an easier solution. Easiest way to get all the C. numbers to Customer number is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Do the parameter names come from the data file (SheetB)?  Or are they hard-coded onto the Template (SheetA)?  If the former, there is an easy Power Query solution that can produce your output from the data file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (run as VBA code):

```
Sub test1()
For i01 = 0 To 100
Worksheets("SheetA").Cells(3 + 12 * i01, 5) = Worksheets("SheetB").Cells(2 + i01, 25)
Next i01
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**[ Indirect with row() ]**

Assuming 'SheetA'E3 column is the target and 'SheetB'Y2 is the source data.

In `SheetA!E3` cell put:

`=INDIRECT("SheetB!Y"&( ( (row()-3) / 12) + 2)`

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then select `SheetA!E3` cell, copy. Then paste in `SheetA!E24`. The formula will update itself.

Idea :

Find the relation between the target cell row number and the source cell row number. [ b > a : 3 > 2 , 15 > 3, 27 > 4 ] leads to a = (b-3)/12 + 2 . (The math is sort of like figuring out a straight line equation from 3 coordinate.) Then use `INDIRECT()` to combine the calculated row number with the column address.

Comment: It's the other way around I think. SheetA is a dumb template and SheetB contains the organized data.

Comment: Done edit as per the clarification. Have a try.. ( ;

Comment: added 1 extra step (the copying part).

Answer (score 0):

Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365, can produce your SheetA given SheetB. Not sure about the effect of the variability you mention.

The query assumes that the correct parameters are listed as column headers in Sheet B.  The column headers will get copied over as parameters to sheet A.

To use Power Query:

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

````
let

//Read in the data
//Change table name in next line to be the "real" table name
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table12"]}[Content],

//set data types based on first entry in the column
//will be independent of the column names
    typeIt = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,
                    List.Transform(
                        Table.ColumnNames(Source), each 
                        {_,Value.Type(Table.Column(Source,_){0})})
    ),

//UNpivot except for the c.number and c.name  columns to create the Parameter and Level columns
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(typeIt, {"C. number", "C. name"}, "Parameter", "Level"),

//Group By C.Number
//Add the appropriate rows for each customer
//And a blank row to separate the customers
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", {"C. number"}, {
        {"All", each _, type table [C. number=nullable number, C. name=nullable text, Parameter=text, Level=any]},
        {"custLabel", (t)=> Table.InsertRows(t,0,{
                                [C. number = null, C. name=null,Parameter = null, Level = null],
                                [C. number = null, C. name=null, Parameter = "Customer Number", Level="Customer Name"],
                                [C. number = null, C. name=null,Parameter = t[C. number]{0}, Level = t[C. name]{0}],
                                [C. number = null, C. name=null,Parameter = "Parameter", Level = "Level"]
        })} 
        }),

//Remove the unneeded columns and expand the remaining table
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"C. number", "All"}),
    #"Expanded custLabel" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "custLabel", {"Parameter", "Level"}, {"Parameter", "Level"}),

//Remove the top blank row
//promote the new blank row to the Header location
    #"Removed Top Rows" = Table.Skip(#"Expanded custLabel",1),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Top Rows", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),

//data type set to text since it will look better on the report
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Customer Number", type text}, {"Customer Name", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type"```
````

**Data**
[image]

**Results**
[image]